# Macro for detecting non-static non-type members in classes

Tags: c++, reflection, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

In *C++ Templates - The complete guide, 2nd edition*, at page 434, a macro is defined to generate predicates testing the existence of a nontype memeber in a class:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

#define DEFINE_HAS_MEMBER(Member)                    \
    template<typename T, typename = void>            \
    struct HasMemberT_##Member : std::false_type {}; \
    template<typename T>                             \
    struct HasMemberT_##Member<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::Member)>> : std::true_type {};
```

The the text reads

> It would not be difficult to modify the partial specialization to exclude cases wehre `&T::Member` is not a pointer-to-member type (which amounts to excluding `static` data members).

So I've played around with `static_assert`s and compiler errors and remember about types of `static` and non-`static` of members of classes:

```cpp
struct A {
    int begin;
    static int end;
};
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&A::begin), decltype(A::begin) A::*>::value, ""); // passes
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&A::end), decltype(A::end)*>::value, "");         // passes
```

And thought that maybe a good modification of the lambda above aimed at detecting non-`static` members only is to change

```cpp
: std::true_type
```

to

```cpp
: std::is_same<decltype(&T::Member), decltype(T::Member) T::*>
```

whereas if I wanted to check for `static` memebers only, I could change it to

```cpp
: std::is_same<decltype(&T::Member), decltype(T::Member)*>
```

Is it really this easy? Or am I overlooking something important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overlooking non-static member *functions*.

The primary use case of the traits created by `DEFINE_HAS_MEMBER` is to check for the existence of a particular method. To borrow from the terminology in the question, a range is defined by having `begin()` and `end()`. While the trait created by the original macro works, your extra condition [does not](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9T4qiUKusJ4wtbNL).

```
prog.cc:7:61: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'int A::begin()'
    7 | static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&A::begin), decltype(A::begin) A::*>::value, "");
      |                                                             ^~~~~
prog.cc:7:72: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    7 | static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&A::begin), decltype(A::begin) A::*>::value, "");
      |
```

The reason in standartese is this:

> **[expr.prim.id]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.id#2) An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access in which the object expression refers to the member's class or a class derived from that class, or
> - to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), or
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand. [ Example:
>
>   ```
>   struct S {
>     int m;
>   };
>   int i = sizeof(S::m);           // OK
>   int j = sizeof(S::m + 42);      // OK
>   ```
>
>   — end example ]

These are the *only* valid uses of something like `T::Member`. Non static member functions don't hit any of the bullets, so the construct is ill-formed when used to define the body of `HasMemberT_##Member`'s specialization. No SFINAE, just a hard error.